# Where does drupal store temporary changes of a view in the database to clear it?

Tags: sql, drupal, drupal-7

Where does drupal store the temporary changes of a view in the **database**?

I know I can usually go into a view and click **cancel**,
however, I have a view that's not working anymore and I can't edit it.

I already tried clearing ***cache_views*** and even replaced the ***views_display*** from an older working database state but didn't help, the only way I can partly solve it is to disable the module but then in the view, I can still see the newly added field and filter criteria (displayed as "Broken/missing handler") from before that should not be there with the old database import restored.

> All changes are stored temporarily. Click Save to make your changes permanent. Click Cancel to discard your changes.

FYI 
I installed nodeviewcount module where I tried sorting by node view COUNT DISTINCT and now when trying to edit the view I get the bellow errors.

> Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached,
>   aborting!

```
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  253992  {main}( )   .../index.php:0
2   0.0789  9184520 menu_execute_active_handler( )  .../index.php:21
3   0.0792  9187896 call_user_func_array:{/var/www/html/opigno/includes/menu.inc:527} ( )   .../menu.inc:527
4   0.0792  9188296 views_ui_edit_page( )   .../menu.inc:527
5   0.0792  9188376 views_ui_edit_page_display( )   .../admin.inc:917
6   0.0792  9188552 views_ui_edit_page_display_tabs( )  .../admin.inc:885
7   0.0793  9207696 view->validate( )   .../admin.inc:1492
8   0.0848  9944976 views_plugin_display->validate( )   .../view.inc:2074
9   0.0862  10124960    views_plugin_display->get_handlers( )   .../views_plugin_display.inc:2819
10  0.0870  10174656    views_handler_sort_group_by_numeric->init( )    .../views_plugin_display.inc:1001
11  0.0871  10179424    views_handler_sort_group_by_numeric->init( )    .../views_handler_sort_group_by_numeric.inc:19
12  0.0872  10183944    views_handler_sort_group_by_numeric->init( )    .../views_handler_sort_group_by_numeric.inc:19
...
...
249 0.1029  11255840    views_handler_sort_group_by_numeric->init( )    .../views_handler_sort_group_by_numeric.inc:19
250 0.1029  11256600    views_get_handler( )    .../views_handler_sort_group_by_numeric.inc:18
251 0.1030  11256696    _views_prepare_handler( )   .../views.module:1296
252 0.1030  11257400    _views_create_handler( )    .../handlers.inc:87
253 0.1030  11258688    views_object->construct( )  .../handlers.inc:65
254 0.1030  11258688    views_object->set_default_options( )    .../base.inc:61
255 0.1030  11258824    views_handler_sort->option_definition( )    .../base.inc:77
256 0.1030  11258824    views_handler->option_definition( ) .../views_handler_sort.inc:36
```

Comment: found it accidentally by creating a unique label name, which I then was able to find in the database lol,  **ctools_object_cache**
posted answer below

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot but think I found it, please comment to confirm

it worked for me to clear **ctools_object_cache**

which seems to store those temporary changes.